# Socket Connection with server : java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "<URL>": No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to stream an byte buffer through socket connection.

Its not making connection with the server.I have added `Internet` & `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission to manifest file.

Here is my socket code :

```
int port = 80;

System.out.println("Connecting to " + ServerUrl.url_audio_call + " on port " + port);
Socket client = new Socket("http://192.168.1.1/call", port);
System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress()); 
OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
out.write(bData);
```

LogCat error :

```
01-22 12:07:03.990: I/System.out(14688): Connecting to http://192.168.1.1/call on port 80
01-22 12:07:03.990: W/System.err(14688): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "http://192.168.1.1/call": No address associated with hostname
01-22 12:07:03.990: W/System.err(14688):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:400)
01-22 12:07:03.999: W/System.err(14688):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
01-22 12:07:03.999: W/System.err(14688):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
01-22 12:07:03.999: W/System.err(14688):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:108)
01-22 12:07:03.999: W/System.err(14688):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
01-22 12:07:03.999: W/System.err(14688):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
01-22 12:07:03.999: W/System.err(14688):    at com.audio_demo.Audio_Call.sendRec(Audio_Call.java:447)
01-22 12:07:03.999: W/System.err(14688):    at com.audio_demo.Audio_Call.access$0(Audio_Call.java:383)
01-22 12:07:03.999: W/System.err(14688):    at com.audio_demo.Audio_Call$2.run(Audio_Call.java:374)
01-22 12:07:03.999: W/System.err(14688):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: did u checked the url through browser?

Comment: can you check with this only `client = new Socket("192.168.1.1", port);`

Comment: Your exception doesn't match your code.

Comment: @EJP what Error I have got. posted that.

Comment: @juned : thanks got solved. I was taking 192.../call removed /call.. this works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"http://192.168.1.1/call" is an URL, "192.168.1.1" is an IP. so you are passing wrong argument, the program cannot understand...

Comment: If you have words ? www.xxxxx.com/xxxx.xml ?

Comment: @delive what do you mean?